# Replace string for a specific column (csv file) in Nodejs

Tags: node.js

I want to  replace string of a particular column from a .csv file in Nodejs

here is my .csv data:

```
ID,Name,openingBalance,closingBalance
"27G","HARRIS TODD",23.22,465.22
"28G","ANGELO RALPH",124.31,555.20
"28N","GRODKO STEVEN",45.22,
"29A","FOWLER ROBERT",65.25,666.00
"29G","PROVOST BRIAN",,253.11
"300","BECKMAN JUDITH",114.21,878.21
```

in the `closingBalance` column there is a **blank** which I need to be replace as **0.00**

I am able to replace the whole data, but not for the specific column,

Can anyone please  help?

I used this for replace string :

```
var fs = require('fs')
fs.readFile(someFile, 'utf8', function (err,data) {
  if (err) {
    return console.log(err);
  }
  var result = data.replace(/string to be replaced/g, 'replacement');

  fs.writeFile(someFile, result, 'utf8', function (err) {
     if (err) return console.log(err);
  });
});
```

Comment: Do you need it only for the cells which are under the `closingBalance` column?

Comment: yes, only for cells which are blank for the particular column closingBalabce

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use regular expression to replace blank cells, but that's easy only for first/last columns:
`data.replace(/,$/gm, ',0.00');`
See [Regex101](https://regex101.com/) for further details and playground

Other way is to parse CSV to AoA:

```js
const csv = `ID,Name,openingBalance,closingBalance
"27G","HARRIS TODD",23.22,465.22
"28G","ANGELO RALPH",124.31,555.20
"28N","GRODKO STEVEN",45.22,
"29A","FOWLER ROBERT",65.25,666.00
"29G","PROVOST BRIAN",,253.11
"300","BECKMAN JUDITH",114.21,878.21`;

const aoa = csv
  .split(/\r?\n/g)
  .map((row) => {
    let [ID, Name, openingBalance, closingBalance] = row.split(',');
    // Fix empty values for "openingBalance" column
    if (!openingBalance.trim()) {
      openingBalance = '0.00';
    }
    // Fix empty values for "closingBalance" column
    if (!closingBalance.trim()) {
      closingBalance = '0.00';
    }
    return [ID, Name, openingBalance, closingBalance]
  });

// now you have AoA with fixed values

console.log(aoa.map((row) => row.join(',')).join('\n'))
```

With this way, you can pre-moderate any column with any code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex to find out blank cells for `closingBalance` column.

The cells for this particular column is the last one in each record which can be easily found by `\n` and `$` in regex.

So to do this:

```js
const result = data.replace(/(,)(?=(\n|$))/g, '$10.00');
```

---

of if you want to find out any blank cells, you can use the following regex:

```js
/(,)(?=(,|\n|$))/g
```

Comment: can you please share me a example of using regex to find out the blank cell

Comment: I've added another regex to cover all the blank cells.